# Firebug - Copy CSS path to command line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firebug

I am trying to modify the firebug plugin for Firefox. What i am trying to achieve is when the user Inspects an element -> clicks 'Copy CSS path', the CSS path should be pasted on the command line of the firebug.

I am able to alert the CSS path from within the firebug. Is there any possible ways to paste the same on the command line?

[image: Guide screenshot]

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of your extension is?

Answer (score 1):

There's a function called `getCommandLine()` located inside the `CommandLine` module. With that function you can get the Command Line. To change the value inside it you can then use its `value` property.

Example code for this can be found in the [`UseInCommandLine` module](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/3eeb241861b3278860f36899902655432d05cc33/extension/content/firebug/console/commands/useInCommandLine.js#L100).

Btw. instead of using `alert()`, which blocks the UI, you can use the extension [FBTrace](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FBTrace) and log messages to its console via `FBTrace.sysout()`.

Sebastian

Comment: Thank you for your time Sebastian, appreciate it. I tried calling the UseInCommandLine module from copyCSSPath module (in reps.js) but it wont call the function for whatever reason. Is there a workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: `copyCSSPath` is used for copying the path to the clipbard, which is not what you want. Also you should not integrate `UseInCommandLine`. As I said it just contains an **example** of how to insert something into the Command Line. Stackoverflow is actually not the right place to talk about all that in detail. You should better continue this thread in the [Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebug). There you'll reach the right people.

Comment: So the [related discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebug/DMoGAELT3yc) was started in the Firebug discussion group. Would be great if you could accept my answer here to close this question.